# How to do some action when any app on Android device is launched?

Tags: android

I want to be able to show "Hello world!" whenever new application on Android is launched.

How to do such thing?

I know it's possible. As example Password protector (http://droidlessons.com/how-to-password-protect-apps-on-android/) shows password screen when another app is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password protectors either monitor the topmost activity or monitor the logcat output. Neither of these methods tell you when an application is launched, only when the topmost activity changes. There isn't any way to properly be told when an activity starts (unless you modify your OS framework for that purpose).